# Don't work bootstrap carousel control bottom

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

"I created element with this tags: href="#carouselID" role="button" data-slide="prev". 
But if i click this element slide doesn't change"

```html
<div class="gal carousel slide" id="carousel2" data-ride="carousel">

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              ...  
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item ">
              ... 
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item ">
             ...
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="carousel__control">
            <a id="carouselPrev" class="arr  " href="#carousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="icon icon-arr_l"></span>
            </a>
            <a id="carouselNext" class="arr  " href="#carousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="icon icon-arr_r"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you include the javascript file needed for your carousel? Do you get any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: I just test out your code, it works regularly as expect. Since I don't have the library for `<span>` Icon tag. The only problem I see is that I have a "invisible" `<span class="icon icon-arr_l"></span> `.  As long as I added some text to the tag, I can click around and no problem with the carousel behavior.